# Updating a database Field based on Condition satisfaction

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am trying to update a database field based on the option that is selected in the View.

```
<select name="unit_type[]" id="unit_type" class="form-control" style="width:150px;">
 <option value="none" selected="" disabled="">Choose</option>
 <option value="Unit">Unit</option>
 <option value="Sub-Unit">Sub-Unit</option>
</select>
```

So in this case if Unit is selected a number should be added to a particular field and if Sub-Unit is selected the number should be added to another field.

### Model

```
public function restocks_update(){
  $item_id=$this->input->post('item_id');
  $qty=$this->input->post('qty');   
  $unit_type=$this->input->post('unit_type');
  for($i=0; $i<count($qty); $i++){
    if($unit_type=="Unit"){
     $this->db->query("UPDATE `stock` SET `quantity_available`=`quantity_available`+'$qty[$i]' WHERE `id`='$item_id[$i]'");
    }else if($unit_type=="Sub-Unit"){
     $this->db->query("UPDATE `stock` SET `convert_qty_available`=`convert_qty_available`+'$qty[$i]' WHERE `id`='$item_id[$i]'");
        }
     }
  }
```

---

The if statement is in a loop because the `select` is also generated dynamically via jquery. The issue at the moment is that the fields are not updating, if i remove the `else if` it updates only one particular field even if it doesn't satisfy the condition.

Comment: I suppose `$unit_type` is array.

Comment: yea it is @u_mulder

Comment: What do you expect when comparing __array__ with __string__?

Comment: **$unit_type** should be unique for your "for loop". As per above code, **$unit_type** will remain same for all of the **$qty**. it should be something like **if ($unit_type[$i] == "Unit")** and same for else if.

Comment: assuming Unit is selected and the number entered is 9 it should be added to the quantity available field, like wise if sub-Unit is selected, the number should be added to the convert_qty_available field rather @u_mulder

Comment: I repeat you compare __array__ with __string__. Not every element of array with string, but __whole__ array with string. Do you see the difference?

Comment: thanks @Yashrajsinh Jadeja it worked

Comment: yeah i do  thanks alot @u_mulder

Comment: @mcprilla79 You're welcome :) You can upvote comment if that's a useful !

Answer (score 0):

try unit_type instead of unit_type[]